# Is there a way to upload higher resolution videos to YouTube (or any video sharing site) directly from your iPhone?

Tags: youtube, video, iphone, vimeo

I currently have an iPhone 4 and while it's very convenient to be able to upload directly from the device to YouTube.com, it only uploads in low resolution, even via WiFi.

Is there a way to upload 720p videos to any web-application (Vimeo/YouTube/etc) directly from the iPhone?

Comment: Certain webapps like vimeo and youtube have mobile counterparts - this was my reasoning for posting on here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a smartphone app. Try [apple.se] instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. After you wait a few minutes a higher resolution version of the video will appear on youtube 320p.
2. The vimeo app is for viewing only and doesn't let you upload.

Answer (score 3):

PixelPipe!
http://pixelpipe.com/

allows you to upload to other sources then Youtube as well. great App.

Comment: I downloaded the pixelpipe iPhone app - then registered an account and linked it to facebook - then proceeded to upload a HD video. I'm not sure where the video went - or even what the purpose of the app is? Does it upload it to facebook? Or is pixelpipe its own website that will host my content?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree with @Pipermac on the **PixelPipe** suggestion!

> This **free app allows iPhone 4 users to
> directly upload their 720P videos to
> YouTube**, as well as Flickr, Facebook,
> MobileMe, Viddler, Posterous and a
> whole slew of other video sharing
> sites. The app evens works via email
> and FTP. The only caveat is that the
> videos cannot be over 200 MB in size.

**Regarding with how to use it, check out this post:
http://islandinthenet.com/2010/07/06/pixelpipe-upload-720p-hd-video-from-iphone-4-to-youtube/
I recommend that post, it gives some great information on the app and how it is used.**

For example:

> A “pipe” is the
> connector between the PixelPipe app
> and one or more destination sites
> where you want your content to be
> uploaded. For example, I set up pipes
> for flickr, picasa, and Dropbox and
> many others.
>
> I setup some of my pipes as default
> routes. This means that any media I
> select to upload will automatically go
> to these default pipes.
>
> For each pipe
> I created, PixelPipe created a routing
> tag. The routing tag explicitly tells
> PixelPipe where to upload the content
> overriding any default routes. If you
> want your content routed to different
> photo sets you can create a routing
> pipe and tag for each one.

Also, given this:

> since other developers are sure to create a similar product now that they know it is possible to upload 720p videos.

**If you don't like the PixelPipe app, it shouldn't be too long before another solution pops up :)**

According to this page, an app called **SmugMug is also 720p uploading enabled**, however I couldn't find much in reference to that on their site.
http://www.tuaw.com/2010/07/01/want-to-upload-720p-from-iphone-4-try-pixelpipe/